# ERROR: not a local package repository

Tags: errors, packages

I am trying to install some necessary packages but always get the Error "not a local package repository" as you see in picture ?

What can I do?

Thank you Very Much[image]

Comment: This does not seem as if you understood the concept of package repo. Please have a look at the questions about adding roots in MikTeX.

Comment: ok thanks. can you please put a link here about those question . @TeXnician

Comment: I searched for `miktex adding roots` and got this as my first result: http://docs.miktex.org/manual/localadditions.html and this as my second: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex both of which are probably just what you're looking for. Happy learning.